# ko binding will not work with durandal

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

I know how to write a costume bind in KO. However, where do I put the code when you are using durandal?  I have used view attach and activate and I get  no love from either.

Here is the code below

```
//knockout-handlers.js
define(function (require) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.slideVisible = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            $(element).toggle(value);
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            var value = valueAccessor(), allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
            var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
            var duration = allBindings.slideDuration || 400;

            if (valueUnwrapped == true)
                $(element).slideDown(duration);
            else
                $(element).slideUp(duration);
        }
    };

    ko.bindingHandlers.fadeVisible = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            $(element).toggle(value);
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            var value = valueAccessor(), allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
            var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
            var duration = allBindings.fadeDuration || 400;

            if (valueUnwrapped == true)
                $(element).fadeIn(duration);
            else
                $(element).fadeOut(duration);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I write all my Knockout extensions (like customer binding handlers and extenders) as a plugin, which I load in `main.js`.

Plugins are just Require modules with an `install` method, which should contian the logic to actually turn the Plugin on. In this case, the `install` method should add the handlers to the `ko` object.

**Main.js**

```
app.configurePlugins({

    //Durandal plugins
    router:true,
    dialog: true,

    //My plugins
    knockoutExtensions: true
});
```

**My Plugin**

```
define(['knockout'], function(ko) {

    var install = function() {
        //You know, do stuff
    };  

    return {
        install: install
    };
});
```

**This method only applies to Durandal 2.0. Earlier versions had a different plugin API**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you can't activate the custom binding with durandal.
Add it anywhere before your view is rendered. I created modules for each handler and then require it in main.js.

I had a similar issue.
Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/durandaljs/NIBVLKN6v1Y